# Why do alias imports break Typescript error reporting?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, import

I am attempting to import re-usable types from another file. When I attempted to import them I was seeing that Typescript stopped working and was no longer reporting errors. As one of the attempted tries at fixing the issue I changed the import to a relative path and the problem went away.

***Alias import breaking Typescript:***

import { PolymorphicComponentProps } from "@interfaces/polymorphic";

***Relative import and Typescript works:***

import { PolymorphicComponentProps } from "../../interfaces/polymorphic";

***For context error checking which works with the relative path but stops working with alias***
[image]

***Attempts to Fix:***

1. Googled lots of things
2. Attempted to play with tsconfig and compared
   to create-react-app to see if I could solve the problem.

I am not sure what to include since I do not know why it is breaking so I started with the tsconfig file:

TS Config JSON:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": false,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "paths": {
      "@components/*": ["components/*"],
      "@core/*": ["core/*"],
      "@constants/*": ["constants/*"],
      "@hooks/*": ["hooks/*"],
      "@interfaces/*": ["interfaces/*"],
      "@utils/*": ["utils/*"],
      "@styles/*": ["styles/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["example", "src", "__tests__"],
  "exclude": ["dist", "node_modules", "src/stories", "webpack", ".vscode"]
}
```